# When to use an array over a pointer, or vice versa

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My understanding is that pointers can be used, among other things, to allow for you to dynamically allocate memory when you need it (and know how much you need) instead of allocating it statically with arrays upfront.

I struggle with determining when its better to save the computation time of dynamic allocation and opt for a larger memory footprint vs. having a larger memory footprint and using some computation time to allocate only the memory I need.

Can someone shed a little light on this subject? Are there any general rules that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dynamically allocated memory when:

- you don't know how much of memory you will need at compile time
- the amount of memory varies when running
- you need large amounts of memory

You should use statically allocated memory when:

- you know the size in compiling time
- the amount of needed memory is low

Using dynamically allocated memory needs the usage of System Calls, this is when you program ask something to the operating system. You have a speed penalty because the process is likely to loose the "processing time" that is given to another process. There are a lot of things that the OS needs to do to accomplish the call. Doing a system call for asking memory is a process much heavier than just writing to an array stored in the process stack.

Comment: Is there a good way to define "low" in "the amount of needed memory is low". I don't have a good sense of where this threshold is.

Comment: This really gets to the heart of the question I was trying to ask (but may have done poorly). However, I'm still interested in what you might consider the low memory threshold.

Comment: @Mark: The stack has a limit, if you can "store" all the memory you need there, that could be "low". But be aware that all functions uses the stack, so if many functions use memory you can run in a stack overflow. Sometimes is safer to use dynamic memory. This all depends on how many memory the program needs and in wich OS is working. There is not a rule for large or low, its just experience.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to use an array when you know either the total size of the data you'll deal with, or at least a maximum size of data. This is especially applicable if you don't really expect tremendous variation in the size -- if (for example) the variation is from 10 to 20 items, it's probably easiest to just allocate 20 regardless and be done with it (unless each item is *really* big).

If you have a lot less idea of the size of the data ahead of time, or (and important possibility) might easily be dealing with too much to plan on putting on the stack, dynamic allocation becomes much more useful. The major weakness of dynamic allocation are that if you're ever going to need to know the size, you need to keep track of it yourself, and it's up to you to ensure that you free the memory when you're done with it. Many (especially of the difficult, nagging) problems in C come down to using memory after it was freed, or forgetting to free memory when you were done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You use a dynamic container when your data is dynamic, or you need to pass the data from different areas of your program.

1 - Dynamic data
Say you've got a list of your neighbors. They build a new house on your street, and you've got to add a guy to the list, but you only allocated enough space for 15 neighbors. This dynamic memory would allow you to increase the size of that container. That's not really how it works. Actually, it finds a new chunk of memory of the necessary size and then copies the old container over.

Or another example. Say you're writing a program that keeps track of an address book. One of your users has ten contacts. Another user is a corporation and there are 50,000 employees that all need to be stored in this address book. You don't want to allocate 50000 spaces for the user who has ten contacts, so you allocate exactly how much you need.

2 - Passing data
When you allocate static data, it is placed on the stack and then inaccessible after out of scope. So if you call some function which generates your array, and then pass the memory address of the array back to its caller, you'll get a runtime error. This is because after that function is exited, the array is out of scope, and it therefore popped off the stack.

However, if you allocate it dynamically, it goes on the heap, and doesn't get free'd until you free it or until the program exits. So you can just keep a pointer to the beginning of the array and use it all throughout your program without worrying about it going out of scope until you want it to.

Comment: Thanks arasmussen, I appreciate the insight. My interest is really in your second example with the address book. Where is the threshold for switching from arrays to pointers? What if the max number of employees was 100, instead of 50000? Is this just a judgement call or are there any rules?

Comment: I would always do it dynamically. There is no sense in hard coding some value, because then you are limiting your program, and you're using memory you don't need to be using. At that point, the only limit in memory is their hardware/setup, not your program. Furthermore, the only time I EVER use a static value is when the array is always the EXACT same size. So if you're storing the positions of 3D coordinates, there are always THREE coordinates, so you would use an array with 3 values. No sense in making that dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are simply contiguous chunks of memory. When you declare an array, you *have* a pointer

```
int foo[5];
```

`foo` (without an index) is a pointer to the first element in that array.

```
foo[0] = 1;
*foo = 1;
```

Those do the same thing, as do:

```
foo[1] = 2;
*(foo + 1) = 2;
```

When you create an array using `int foo[5];` you're creating on the stack. This is local to the current function and once you return from the function it is no longer valid. If you `malloc()` memory, you're creating the array on the heap (and have a pointer to it)

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
foo[0] = 1;
*foo = 1;
```

You have to manage this memory yourself, and `free()` it when you're done with it:

```
free(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has an accepted answer. Let me talk about a slightly different thing. In C sometimes you can use an array with size determined at runtime. For example:

```
void foo (int a[], int n) {
    int buf[n];
    /* do something with buf[] */
}
```

This kind of arrays get allocated in the stack and is of variable size. The difference from doing malloc is that you do not have to `free()` the memory; that is taken care of when the function call exists. Of course this also means that you possibly cannot return the address of the array.